# What happened to my Loftwing?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In Skyward Sword, my Loftwing didn't appear when Zelda pushed me off the ledge. I know I have to find out what happened to it now, but I have no idea where to go. Someone suggested asking the people in the plaza where to look, but no one there even mentions my Loftwing or anything. I am mostly running around in circles at this point, and I end up talking to the same people over and over.

What am I missing? Where do I need to go to find my bird?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to talk to the professor outside the upper exit of the academy, then head to the spot marked Plaza on the map, which should trigger a cutscene.

There are more steps to it after that, but I'm not sure if you want more than that or not.

Comment: That's enough - I managed to find my way from there. I can't believe how stuck I was.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the water fall with a sword from the sparring hall